# A good way to offset all thats drawn to the canvas 0.5 px?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want the canvas to by default draw true pixels. I wish I could just add a css prop to offset it 0.5 pixels, but as you know, one can't.

Any awesome fix out there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply transform the context itself:

```
context.translate(0.5, 0.5);
```

Everything that is drawn next will now be offset half pixel.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `-0.5` instead because you are drawing it 0.5px farther.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 A pixel is by default placed so it goes 0.5 in all direction with canvas - the position represents its center. So by adding 0.5 you will get the otherwise hidden half (if at border) to show. If you used negative values the first pixel wouldn't show.